# How to interact with Smart contracts Locally

Tags: contract-development, contract-debugging

I'm interested in writing a some code that will interact with Aave and a few other Defi projects such as uniswap.

I've downloaded truffle an ganache.
However I'm bit confused on how to write a contract that will interact with Aave locally.
I haven't gone over all of Aave's code but even if I deployed their contracts locally they still are probably dependent on external smart contracts / oracles.

At this point I'm a bit confused, should I even bother with local block chains for testing, or should the be strictly developed on a test network?

Comment: It is always better to start with ganache as a local blockchain, with ganache u can fork other chains like main net or any testnet. To write a smart contract u can start buy using remix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your project requires that you use an existing contract that has some volume of transactions going through it then using the testnet is the best choice.

You can also fork the testNet or even the main net to a certain block and take it from there to start your testing. here you can use any account and give yourself a quasi-infinite balance to try anything on the network with the existing chain data as a start.

Using a local private network is good when you are developing all the components to your project ecosystem yourself or as part of an organization that does so.